# Enable visual-fill-column-mode only in text and programming mode

Tags: hooks, minor-mode

I am currently using `visual-fill-column-mode` and `visual-line-mode` in emacs with the following:

```
(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'visual-fill-column-mode)
(global-visual-line-mode t)
(define-key visual-line-mode-map [remap kill-line] nil)
```

This enable both mode everywhere, but I would like:

- `visual-line-mode` to be enable everywhere **but** in terminal (e.g. `ansi-term`)
- `visual-fill-column-mode` to be enable only in "text" and "programming"

Currently I have the following hook for `ansi-term` but it does not work:

```
(defun my-term-hook ()
  (visual-fill-column-mode nil)
  (visual-line-mode nil))
(add-hook 'term-load-hook 'my-term-hook)
```

And I don't on which hook I could bind those mode to enable them in all programming mode (I know about `text-mode-hook` for text mode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text-mode-hook` for all text modes and `prog-mode-hook` for all programming language modes.

Of course, "all" should be takes with a grain of salt. Some modes does not inherit from the standard modes, in which case please contact the maintainer and report that as a bug.

Comment: Thanks, `prog-mode-hook` solve my problem.